# Android : Change image when user clicks and set it to original afterwards

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

I am working on an Android application in which I have an ImageView, which is set in XML directly(default image). Now, when the user clicks on the image, I would like to change it with another image only so the user knows that it's pressed. When I looked up, I can find onClickListener, but that changes the image and does not revert to the old one. I am just looking for some way to show that the button is pressed.

XML code :

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/shirtImage"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:src="@drawable/shirt" />
```

Activity code :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        shirt = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.shirtImage);

 shirt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shirt.setImageResource(R.drawable.shirtactive);
            }
        });

    }
```

Thank you.

*Updated  code*

```
  shirt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    shirt.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    shirt.setImageResource(R.drawable.shirtactive);
                    return true;
                }
                else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    shirt.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
                    shirt.setImageResource(R.drawable.shirt);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a xml file in your drawable folder (with name selector_imageview for example) with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shirtactive" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shirtactive" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shirt"/>

</selector>
```

And set in your ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shirtImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_imageview" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector in drawable folder and set it as source.
Create image_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_image"/>
</selector>
```

Then in layout,

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shirtImage"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:src="@drawable/image_selector" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You see, onClickListener runs its callback only if you clicked on View. It means, that you pressed it, and then fast enough release it. In your case you have two options:

**Variant I**

Implementing that programmatically you need to call `setOnTouchListener` and in `onTouch` callback you need to check MotionEvent action. If it's DOWN, then you need to change your image and "pressed" one, if UP, then change back to yours.

**Variant II**

You need to provide xml withi this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_image"/>
</selector>
```

This will gives you effect that you wanted. Also, I suggest you to use this approach, since it's less boilerplate and more flexible, because:

- You can provide another states and images for them, for example, "focused" state or "selected" state
- You can override this xml with more specific one (for example, for versions >= 21 and provide not simple changing image on press, but ripple effect, or for one countries make one pressed image, for another another pressed image).

**Updated**

If you want to use animation when change view state from "default" to "pressed" and vice versa, you need to use Variant I. Here is sample:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //make fade-in animation here
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //make fade-out animation here
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I get fade-in effect for press with this?

Comment: @WeareBorg If you will use first variant then in Action DOWN and Action UP you can do whatever you want. I will add example in my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when the user clicks on the image, I would like to change it with
>   another image only so the user knows that it's pressed.

then you want to toggle between the two images. You want to apply the behaviour of a `CheckBox` to an `ImageView`. Yon can either keep track of the current image set, using `View#setTag` and `View#getTag` for instance, or subclass ImageView and let it implement the interface Checkable. This way you could have a selector with the state `android:state_checked`. I would go rather for the latter, even though the former is easily implemented

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you. you need to reset image to default image on ACTION_UP

```
imageButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        // Press stat
        return true;
    }
    else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

        // Relese Stat
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Cool, this is working nicely. Any animation for fade-in and fade-out you might know? The duration is very less, and doesn't seem that smooth. Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to check out this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html)

Comment: There is no image change in the link you provided.

Comment: you can set image before starting animation

Comment: I tried both, setting the image first, then starting animation and vice-versa. Still wouldn't see the updated image. I have updated my main post. Can you please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer are okay for your purpose. But I suggest use svg files as drawble and use tint mode in imageview attribute. This is best way mostly use in material design.

Comment: R u sure ? Actually AppComapt library comes with backward compatibility. So thought tint works good with backward compatibility